# The second derivative of the second norm raised to the power of p

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization

I have a function
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{p}\|x\|_2^p, \ p>1$$

I need to calculate $d^2f(x)$. I've found first derivative:
$$df(x)=\|x\|^{p-2}_2x^Tdx$$

Could someone please help me understand how I can take the second derivative?

Comment: By second derivative, do you mean the Hessian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are halfway there!  Take $x$ to be a $n\times 1$ column vector. By the product rule,

$$\begin{align}
D^2f(x)&=D \|x\|_2^{p-2}x'\\
&=(p-2)\|x\|_2^{p-4}xx'+\|x\|_2^{p-2}\mathbb{I}_n\\
&=\|x\|_2^{p-4}\left((p-2)xx'+\|x\|_2^{2}\mathbb{I}_n\right).
\end{align}$$